# Adding height to a password box input

Tags: html, input, height

I am trying to add a password box into my website with custom height but i was not able to do so, though i was able to add a width style but not height.

```
<input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
       class="" style="width: 500px;" style="height: 23px;"/>
```

I tried adding `style="height:` but nothing really happens

appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: you cant have the same style attribute twice, you need to unite them into one: `style="width: 500px; height:50px;"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two style attributes...

```
<input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
       class="" style="width: 500px; height: 23px;"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4zjomh7/

In HTML, SGML and XML, attributes cannot be repeated, and should only be defined in an element once and so your code wouldn't have conformed to HTML standards...

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. i am still learning my way through but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want the text in the field to be centered, you can use Padding to do this.

Padding works this way: `padding: top right bottom left;` you can set one or just the options you need.

```html
<input type="password" style="padding: 10px;" value="hello there">
```

Answer (score 1):

Always best to 'wrap' your styles in CSS; eg

```
css

.Passwd
{
    width: 500p;
    height: 23px;
}

html

<input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
   class="Passwd"/>
```

I find it easier to find the css when I need to 'play' with the style settings

Comment: does this auto-adjust the box size according to the text "Password"?

Answer (score 0):

I added height like this.

```
<input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
       class="" style="width: 500p; height: 23px;"/>
```

It worked well.